# xsd: define an array of (not predefined) attributes for a given tag

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to add localization to multiple language in an XML.
The tag containing the text is called "saluto", at the moment it looks like:

```
<saluto>buon giorno</saluto>
```

In order to add the new translations, one of the most compact solutions I can think is the use of attributes to pass the different translations, so I will avoid tag duplication:

```
<saluto IT="buon giorno" EO="bonan tagon" EN="good morning" CN="早安" PL="dzień dobry" />
```

The problem is how to write an XSD rule that will allow to do this, considering that in the future new languages can be added and I wouldn't like to change the XSD.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one of the most compact solutions I can think is the use of attributes to pass the different translations, so I will avoid tag duplication

I would humbly suggest that compactness, while nice to have, should not be your main consideration. If compactness really is the most important criterion then XML is probably the wrong choice of file format.

> The problem is how to write an XSD rule that will allow to do this, considering that in the future new languages can be added and I wouldn't like to change the XSD

If you specify a list of valid language names in your XSD then any *new* language names will fail to validate against v1 of your XSD. The usual solution is to extend the XSD when new requirements come along. Why is that not a viable approach for your use case?

An alternative approach, almost as compact, would be:

```
<saluto lang="EN">Good morning</saluto>
```

The list of allowed values for the attribute `lang` could then be specified in a simple type restriction with one `<xs:enumeration>` for each language. Future versions of the XSD could simply add new enumerations.

Comment: Finally i used the format, to avoid the problems you mentioned:
<saluto lingua="IT">Buon giorno</saluto> <saluto lingua="EO">Bonan tagon</saluto>...